# override core controller in custom module in Magento

Tags: module, overriding, customization, extend, magento-1.9.1

HI i have to extend the core controller in my own module for this i am referencing the below link
http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/

below is my module  structure

/var/www/magento1.9/app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--we need to enable this module as any other if-->
<!--you wish to do it as standalone module extension-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/var/www/magento1.9/app/code/local/Inchoo/Coreextended/controllers/Frontend/Customer/AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
//we need to add this one since Magento wont recognize it automatically
class Inchoo_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{//here, you extended the core controller with our
public function indexAction()
{
parent::indexAction();
//you can always use default functionality
}
public function myactionAction()
{
//my code
//you can write your own methods / actions
}
public function mymethod()
{
//my code
//you can write your own methods
}
public function loginAction()
{

    echo "hello";
//finally you can write your code that will rewrite the whole core method
//and you can call for your own methods, as you have full control over core controller
}
}
```

/var/www/magento1.9/app/code/local/Inchoo/Coreextended/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
                <customer>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Inchoo_Coreextended before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">Inchoo_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer</Inchoo_Coreextended>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

but when i am accessing the  `http://localhost/magento1.9/index.php/customer/account/login/`  it shows core  login action  and it is not switching from my module   Can you please suggest where i am doing mistake .

Comment: Concerning aforementioned tutorial, I highly suggest to avoid any tabs, spaces, line breaks etc. in tag contents (as it was with controller name in tutorial, because tabs and line breaks may not be trimmed and extension doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this by making changes in following file:

> app/etc/modules/Inchoo_Coreextended.xml .

Before:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

After:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> codepool should be codePool